# PostAsync works with xml but not pdf files

Tags: c#, post, async-await

I can't figure out what is wrong and why this post returns `Error 500` only with pdf files, it is working normally with xml files.
I've tried changing the headers values in many ways it keeps respond same error:

Server accused:

`MultipartException: Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Stream ended unexpectedly`

Content:

```
public class UploadRequest
{
    public byte[] fileToUpload { get; set; }
    public string fileType { get; set; }
    public string fileReference { get; set; }
    public string issueDate { get; set; }
    public string userId { get; set; }
    public string headerValue { get; set; }

    public string fileName { get; set; }

    public UploadRequest(string fileName, byte[] fileToUpload, String fileType, String fileReference, 
        String issueDate, String userId, String headerValue)
    {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.fileToUpload = fileToUpload;
        this.fileType = fileType;
        this.fileReference = fileReference;
        this.issueDate = issueDate;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.headerValue = headerValue;
    }

    public MultipartFormDataContent getFormContent(){

      var fileToUploadContent = new ByteArrayContent(fileToUpload, 0, fileToUpload.Length);            
      fileToUploadContent.Headers.Add("content-type", "application/" + headerValue); // 'pdf' or 'xml'            

      return new MultipartFormDataContent
        {
            { fileToUploadContent, "file", fileName},
            { new StringContent(fileType), "fileType"},
            { new StringContent(fileReference), "fileReference"},
            { new StringContent(issueDate), "issueDate"},
            { new StringContent(userId), "userId"}
        };
    }
}
```

Post Method:

```
public class Upload
{
   private HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
   private string urlBase = "https://xxxxxxxx-xx.xx.us10.hana.xxxxx.com/file/upload/ImportDeclaration/";

  public async void sendFilesWs(UploadRequest requestData, Int64 ?processNumber)
  {
    try
    {
      client.BaseAddress = new Uri(urlBase);
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Apikey xxxx-d87a-xxxx-9a36-xxxx");
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Origin", "https://xxxxxx.com");                

    } catch(Exception e)
    {
    // has  header
    }
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(processNumber.ToString(), requestData.getFormContent());
    string contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    //Console.Write(response.StatusCode);
  }
}
```

Calling post:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  var pdfFile= System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(this.Dir + "\\" + _fileName);

  var uploadRequest = new UploadRequest(_fileName, PdfFile, "Other",
                            number,
                            DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"),
                            "99999999", "pdf");

  Upload _Upload = new Upload();
  _Upload.sendFileWs(uploadRequest, _processNumber);
}
```

Many Thanks in advance.

Update:
Server side was build on `Spring Boot 2`

spring boot 2 no filters:

```
@Override
@PostMapping("/{documentTag}/{documentId}")
public ResponseEntity<?> postFile(
    @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
    @RequestParam("fileType") String fileType,
    @RequestParam("fileReference") String fileReference,
    @RequestParam("issueDate") String issueDate,
    @RequestParam("userId") String userId,
    @PathVariable(value = "documentTag") String documentTag,
    @PathVariable(value = "documentId") Long documentId) {

    logger.info("File received by File Service");

    FileInformation fileInformation = new FileInformation(FileType.of(fileType), fileReference, issueDate, userId);
    return fileUploadBusiness.upload(file, fileInformation, documentTag, documentId, request.getHeader("Authorization")
);
```

Comment: I wold love to Sir but the company wont allow me to share the endpoint, the only thing i can do its to put the class constructor in it. just a sec.. thanks anyway...

Comment: What type of app is this?  E.g. web app, console, WPF, webforms?

Comment: @sellotape I'm testing it using windows forms

Comment: Can you show more context around the bit you call "Calling post", e.g. the method signature and how it's called. We'll basically need to see the methods it calls from the UI event down to `sendFilesWs`

Comment: @sellotape the hole class upload request its there the method 'sendFileWs' can be called from a button or on form load, same result ... anyhow I´m updating it. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change the signature of your `Form1_Load` event to

```
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

With very few exceptions, UI events are the only time you should see `async void` in your code.  After changing that, change the signature of `sendFilesWs()` to

```
public async Task sendFilesWs(UploadRequest requestData, Int64 ?processNumber)
```

and then in your `Form1_Load` event call it like this instead:

```
await _Upload.sendFileWs(uploadRequest, _processNumber);
```

---

The way you had it before:

- the event fires
- you call `_Upload.sendFileWs()`
- it returns control to your event as soon as its code hits `await client.PostAsync()`
- the event code continues, completes, and `_Upload` goes out of scope
- at some point (exactly when you can't be sure, hence why you get unpredictable results), the garbage collector cleans up `_Upload`, including the `HttpClient` it contains, which will terminate any connections it had open, and hence "Stream ended unexpectedly" on the server.

---

With the changes above, the event now receives a `Task` that it can await, so `_Upload` now only goes out of scope once its work it complete, preventing the issue.